# Get Max occurence of element in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hello all i have 2 class for the example i will name it A and B

A is a list and every A element have a list of B element.
B element have a type

I want to get a B element by occurance of it in my list of B element.

```
var listB = A
  .SelectMany(a => a.B);

var listBId = listB
  .Where(b => b.Type == SelectedType)
  .Select(b => b.Id);

var IdMaxoccur = listBId
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
  .First()
  .Key;
```

I find this a bit heavy for just get the max occurence of an id in a list....
Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Since this is working code you want to improve, your question would be better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: Didn't know this exist... I don't use stack overflow often :P

Comment: If you use [a `MaxBy()` extension method for linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy/) you could write this along the lines of: `var result = A.OfType(SelectedType).MaxBy(x => x.Id).Key;` (somewhat simplified from what you'd actually need).

Comment: Its a shared project with a compagny i would prefeer not to have another extension to install on every post who need to compile this.

Comment: @Jebik You can just write a class to do it, like any other code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's missing a `SelectMany` and not what `OfType` does, and not the correct use of `MaxBy`...

Comment: @Rawling Yeah I was really just telling him about MaxBy() rather than trying to give a proper answer (hence it's a comment, not an answer!)

Comment: Please note that your current code will throw exception if there will be no B elements of selected type and listBId will be empty. This is because `First` keyword expects at least one record to be in result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is good enough if you rewrite and simplify it a bit and handle case when your list is empty. This code assumes that 0 is not a valid Id.

```
var result = A
    .SelectMany(x => x.B)
    .Where(x => x.Type == selectedType)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id, new { Id = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Max ID = {0}, Count = {1}", result.Id, result.Count);
```

If you still think that your existing code is too complex, you could write extension method to hide complexity

```
public static int TryGetBIdWithMaxOccur(this IEnumerable<A> input, SelectedTypeEnum selectedType)
{
    var result = input
        .SelectMany(x => x.B)
        .Where(x => x.Type == selectedType)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id, new { Id = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var result = A.TryGetBIdWithMaxOccur(SelectedTypeEnum.CoolValue);

if(result != default(int))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit shorter you can put the `Where` selector inside `SelectMany` and use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/Bb534304(v=VS.110).aspx) overload:

```
var idMaxOccur = A
    .SelectMany(a => a.B.Where(b => b.Type == selectedType))
    .GroupBy(b => b.Id, b => b.Id)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First().Key;
```

Comment: This is not correct as it will return Id with least occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea

```
var bs = A.SelectMany().Where().Select(b=>b.Id).OrderBy();
int current = -1, maxB = -1;   // make sure it is stub Id
int currentCount = 0, maxCount = 0;
foreach(var b in bs)
{
    if (b != current)
    {
         // check if previous was max
         if (currentCount > maxCount)
         {
              maxB = current;
              maxCount = currentCount;
         }

         // change current
         current = b;
         currentCount = 0;
    }

    currentCount ++;
}
```